# Как правильно подключить bootstrap и jquery в webpack-encore на symfony 4.2?

Tags: bootstrap, webpack, symfony4

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём заключается проблема подключения bootstrap и jquery в webpack-encore на symfony 4.2?

```
//webpack.config.js
    var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

    Encore
         .setOutputPath('public/build/')
         .setPublicPath('/build')
         .enableSassLoader(function(sassOptions) {}, {
             resolveUrlLoader: false
          })
         .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
         .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
         .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
         .enableBuildNotifications()
         .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
         .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
         .addStyleEntry('styles', './assets/app.scss')
         .autoProvidejQuery()
   ;
   module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Установлены "sass-loader": "^7.1.0", "node-sass": "^4.11.0", "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.0", "jquery": "^3.3.1".
В файле assets/app.scss подключаю @import "~bootstrap-sass"; и при вызове команды yarn dev выдаёт ошибку:

```
    Running webpack ...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                                                                                                      22:03:08


 error  in ./assets/app.scss

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

undefined
  ^
      Invalid CSS after "if": expected selector, was "(typeof jQuery === "
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

Comment: @import '....bootstrap.css'; ? Может с импортами, например бутстрапа